# Do weapon specific perks work while dual striking in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim, if you do a dual strike, where you hit both attack buttons to hit with both weapons simultaneously, do the weapon-specific perks (sword crit, mace ignore armor, axe... something) apply?

There are several combinations of this question I'm wondering about, but I'm guessing they all have the same answer.  For example, does Fighting Stance work when you are dual wielding?  And do Savage Strike and Dual Savagery stack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, based on several types of evidence.

1. I dual-wield exclusively and I know that Fighting Stance, Savage Strike, Dual Savagery etc. stack.
2. The dagger specific perks from the Sneak perk tree stack with the perks from the One-Handed perk tree.
3. The [UESP One-Handed Page](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:One-handed) has a section on dual-wielding which says:

   > Allows the use of two perk proficiencies at once, such as Hack and Slash, Bladesman, or Bone Breaker, by mixing weapon types.

   and

   > Dual Savagery and Dual Fury can make for almost scary damage output.